# maintaining dynamically assigned CSS class after page refresh

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3

The issue:

The menu is assigned a selected class based on the click in MVC3 . The class however was reset after the page was reloaded.

Tried to solve it using jQuery cookies but the values are not assigned correctly .. (The class is assigned after 2-3 clicks on that menu and not on the first click .

The menu example is:

```
 <div class="wrap-nav">
  <div class="menu">

        <ul>
        <li> @Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Index", "Profile") </li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Search", "Index", "Search") </li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contacts", "ContactView", "Contact")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log Out", "LogOut", "Profile") </li>

            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Menu .wrap-nav .menu ul li a").click(function () {
        $.cookie("selectedMenu", $(this).text());
});

   $("#Menu .wrap-nav .menu ul li a").each(function () {
        if ($(this).text() == $.cookie("selectedMenu")) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

used Jquery on the pages which are opened after menu clicks.

for example. On profile page , have written the code to assign profile link the class .

Answer (score 0):

just

```
$('selector')addClass();
```

Should work? In php I write like this

```
$('selector').addClass('<?php echo $dynamically_load_classname?>')
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply . the issue is that the class needs to be determined when the menu is clicked. after a page refresh, there does not seem to be any way of how to remember the clicked menu other than cookies.. did also try the suggested approach and it assigned the class but the class was reset when the page was reloaded